# How to properly put the reformatted value from a JSON file into it's own respective parent

Tags: javascript, json

## Problem

All of the reformatted values are being put into the same first blockquote instead of their own parent

[image: screenshot of problem]

---

### Question

How can i reformat my code to properly display only the respective child inside its parent blockquote?

#### JS

```
var brewer = document.getElementsByClassName('author-raw');
for (var contrib = 0; contrib < brewer.length; contrib++) {
  var matches = brewer[contrib].innerHTML.match(/(.*)\s\<([a-z]*)\>/);
  var output = `${matches[1]} <a href="https://www.twitter.com/${matches[2]}" target="_blank">@${matches[2]}</a>`;
  document.querySelector('blockquote cite').innerHTML += output;
}
```

#### Demo

Working demo is available on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/oyKvwa)

#### HTML Sample

```
<blockquote>
  <p>Allow the bay leaves to steep in the boil for extra time to extract some bitterness. The bitterness is really important to bring balance to an otherwise sweet beer.</p>
  <div class="author">
    <span class="author-raw" aria-hidden="true">Sam Mason <samjbmason></span>
    <cite></cite>
  </div>
</blockquote>
```

---

### Background

Using Vue and Axios in my app I am hitting the punkapi to get a listing of beers which includes tips from the brewers. For the brewer's name I am getting a raw JSON value such as

```
"contributed_by":"Sam Mason <samjbmason>"
```

the first part is the name, the second part is the Twitter username. I have been able to take those values and reformat them as name and linked Twitter account. The generated innerHTML is now something like

```
Sam Mason <a href="https://www.twitter.com/samjbmason" target="_blank"> samjbmason</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update this line

```
document.querySelector('blockquote cite').innerHTML += output;
```

to this

```
brewer[contrib].closest('div').querySelector('cite').innerHTML = output;
```

The `querySelector` will with this start from its inital `span`, go one step up, to the `div` parent, and then select a `cite`, which will be each `span`'s sibling.

Updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NzQWGg?editors=0010)

Stack snippet

```js
var brewer = document.getElementsByClassName('author-raw');
for (var contrib = 0; contrib < brewer.length; contrib++) {
  var matches = brewer[contrib].innerHTML.match(/(.*)\s\<([a-z]*)\>/);
  var output = `${matches[1]} <a href="https://www.twitter.com/${matches[2]}" target="_blank">@${matches[2]}</a>`;
  brewer[contrib].closest('div').querySelector('cite').innerHTML = output;
}
```

```css
.author-raw {
  display: none;
}
cite {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <blockquote>
    <p>Wheat and flaked oats can help to add to the body of the beer. This makes up for the lack of alcoholic bite.</p>
    <div class="author">
      <span class="author-raw" aria-hidden="true">Lars Gregori <choas></span>
      <cite></cite>
    </div>
  </blockquote>
    
  <blockquote>
    <p>Mash the blueberries before adding to the kettle. This will help with flavour extraction and turning your wort a nice shade of purple.</p>
    <div class="author">
      <span class="author-raw" aria-hidden="true">Ali Skinner <AliSkinner></span>
      <cite></cite>
    </div>
  </blockquote>  
    
  <blockquote>
    <p>Be careful with the Motueka additions. It has an intense citrus character that is often tempered by using in conjunction with other hops.</p>
    <div class="author">
      <span class="author-raw" aria-hidden="true">Matt Ball <GeordieMatt></span>
      <cite></cite>
    </div>
  </blockquote>
  <blockquote>
    <p>Allow the bay leaves to steep in the boil for extra time to extract some bitterness. The bitterness is really important to bring balance to an otherwise sweet beer.</p>
    <div class="author">
      <span class="author-raw" aria-hidden="true">Sam Mason <samjbmason></span>
      <cite></cite>
    </div>
  </blockquote>
</section>
```

---

Another option, maybe even better, could be to use `nextElementSibling`

```
brewer[contrib].nextElementSibling.innerHTML = output;
```

```js
var brewer = document.getElementsByClassName('author-raw');
for (var contrib = 0; contrib < brewer.length; contrib++) {
  var matches = brewer[contrib].innerHTML.match(/(.*)\s\<([a-z]*)\>/);
  var output = `${matches[1]} <a href="https://www.twitter.com/${matches[2]}" target="_blank">@${matches[2]}</a>`;
  brewer[contrib].nextElementSibling.innerHTML = output;

}
```

```css
.author-raw {
  display: none;
}
cite {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <blockquote>
    <p>Wheat and flaked oats can help to add to the body of the beer. This makes up for the lack of alcoholic bite.</p>
    <div class="author">
      <span class="author-raw" aria-hidden="true">Lars Gregori <choas></span>
      <cite></cite>
    </div>
  </blockquote>
    
  <blockquote>
    <p>Mash the blueberries before adding to the kettle. This will help with flavour extraction and turning your wort a nice shade of purple.</p>
    <div class="author">
      <span class="author-raw" aria-hidden="true">Ali Skinner <AliSkinner></span>
      <cite></cite>
    </div>
  </blockquote>  
    
  <blockquote>
    <p>Be careful with the Motueka additions. It has an intense citrus character that is often tempered by using in conjunction with other hops.</p>
    <div class="author">
      <span class="author-raw" aria-hidden="true">Matt Ball <GeordieMatt></span>
      <cite></cite>
    </div>
  </blockquote>
  <blockquote>
    <p>Allow the bay leaves to steep in the boil for extra time to extract some bitterness. The bitterness is really important to bring balance to an otherwise sweet beer.</p>
    <div class="author">
      <span class="author-raw" aria-hidden="true">Sam Mason <samjbmason></span>
      <cite></cite>
    </div>
  </blockquote>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be done with parentNode

```
brewer[contrib].parentNode.parentNode.innerHTML += output;
```